# Complex eigenvalue prevents a matrix to have a real eigenbasis

Tags: linear-algebra

How to prove

> If a real matrix $A(n\times n)$ has one complex eigenvalue, this matrix doesn't have a real eigenbasis.

I have a proof for it but I don't like it, because I think it's too complicated and doesn't capture the essence of this statement.

*My proof:* Assume it has a real eigenbasis $v_1,\dotsc,v_n$. So they are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Set these real eigenvalues $t_1,\dotsc,t_m$ ($m<n$), the complex eigenvalue is $c_1$, and the complex vector $k_1$, by using the conclusion: The vectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are linearly independent (if more than one vector corresponding to one eigenvalue are linearly independent, you can add these vectors and the conclusion is still true), so
$v_1,\dotsc,v_n$, $k_1$ are $n+1$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$, which is impossible.

Are there any better proofs for this problem?

Comment: If $A$ has an eigenbasis with eigenvalues $(t_1,\dots,t_n)$ then every eigenvalue $c$ is equal to some $t_k.$ That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ has eigenbasis $v_1, \dots, v_n$ then denoting the matrix with columns $v_i$ by $P$, $PAP^{-1}$ is diagonal, with entries (along the diagonal) the eigenvalues of $A$. If $A$ and $P$ are real matrices then so is $PAP^{-1}$.

Comment: Why the complex eigenvalue must show up in $PAP^-1$,maybe one real eigenvalue appears more than once along the diagonal.(Since there can be linearly independent vectors corresponding to the same eigenvalue .

Comment: @zxZ If $w$ is an eigenvector of $A$ then $Pw$ is an eigenvector of $PAP^{-1}$ with the same eigenvalue, and now compare the $i$th coordinate for any $(Pw)_i \ne 0$.